# 500 jquery.min.js:4 (internal server error) laravel ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

im new in ajax, and im tried [this](http://tutsnare.com/post-data-using-ajax-in-laravel-5/) tutorial but i get 500 jquery.min.js:4  (internal server error), i dont have any idea to solve this, here is the code :

view :

```
  <div class="secure">Secure Login form</div>
  {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'account/login','method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'myform')) !!}
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
       {!! Form::text('email','',array('id'=>'','class'=>'form-control span6','placeholder' => 'Email')) !!}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
    {!! Form::password('password',array('class'=>'form-control span6', 'placeholder' => 'Please Enter your Password')) !!}
    </div>
  </div>
  {!! Form::button('Login', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

jquery :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.send-btn').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
       url: 'login',
       type: "post",
       cache: false,
       data: {'email':$('input[name=email]').val(), '_token': 
       $('input[name=_token]').val()},
       success: function(data){
       alert(data);
      }
     });
    });
   });
  </script>
```

controller :

```
  public function login() {
  // Getting all post data
  if(Request::ajax()) {
    $data = Input::all();
    print_r($data);die;
  }
}
```

routes :

```
Route::get('account/login', function() {
  return View::make('login');
});
Route::post('account/login', 'AccountController@login');
```

Comment: When you've check your `Network Tab` in your `console` and see your `ajax url` (e.g `account/login`), Did you see the `preview` of your given response?

Comment: which version of laravel you work?

Comment: Try adding `{!! Form::token() !!}` before `{!! Form::close() !!}`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you get 500 error code because you´re not sending any csrf token with your ajax request, try this in your javascript

```
$('.send-btn').click(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }   
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: 'login',
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        data: {'email':$('input[name=email]').val(), '_token': 
        $('input[name=_token]').val()},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});
```

If this doenst work you should open your console->network->click in your request and give us the response preview so we can help you